# C#, Android: Build own event listener

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

here is the problem. I am using a custom component from someone else called a "Fancy showcase view". It focuses on buttons in my activity on highlights them with a text as a tutorial through the app. I am starting the first message, and when the user dissmises this by clicking anywhere in the activity, the next button is supposed to be highlighted. Unfortunately, the component, which otherwise is perfect, doesnt have a listener implemented like "OnDismis" of the first tutorial view so the next could start. Just putting both into code one after the other skips the second one. It also tried working with lifecycle methods, such as OnFocuseChanged() but even after the tutorial gets dismissed, this method isnt called a second time. What would you guys say is the best way to handle this? Here is what is NOT working:

```
            try
            {
                new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(this) // if this crashes, we need clean rebuild
                    .Title(title1)
                    .TitleStyle(0, (int)GravityFlags.Center | (int)GravityFlags.Center)
                    .Build()                      
                    .Show();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "There was an error ... " + e, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }

            try
            {
                new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(this) // if this crashes, we need clean rebuild
                    .Title("TEST")
                    //.TitleStyle(0, (int)GravityFlags.Center | (int)GravityFlags.Center)
                    .FocusOn(txtL)
                    .Build()
                    .Show();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "There was an error ... " + e, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
```

The second one doesnt show up. There are no event handlers and I cannot make use of lifecycle methods. Click counting wouldnt work either, since the user might click on the activity while it is loading so hard coded values arent a good option either. Any ideas?

Thanks:)

Comment: Can you point us to the source of the show case view?

Comment: Sure and you are gonna laugh: this version DOES HAVE handlers BUT it is for android studio (java) and i am using a ported version that just doesnt have that:  https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView/wiki/2.-Customized-Usage

Comment: Ok than you might want to contribute the missing pieces or you might want to create a binding project. Both does not seems to be that complicated.

Comment: @innomotionmedia Use the `FancyShowCaseQueue`, you add individual `FancyShowCaseView`s to it and when you "Show()" the queue, each FancyShowCaseView happens in the order in-which you added them to the queue.

Comment: @SushiHangover can you elaborate? and please put as answer so i can mark as good :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FancyShowCaseQueue` to control the sequence.

You add individual `FancyShowCaseView`s to it and when you "Show()" the queue, each FancyShowCaseView happens in the order in-which you added them to the queue.

Example:

```
var fancyView1 = new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(this)
                  .Title("StackOverflow 1")
                  .FocusOn(button1)
                  .Build();
var fancyView2 = new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(this)
                  .Title("StackOverflow 2")
                  .FocusOn(button1)
                  .Build();

var fancyQueue = new FancyShowCaseQueue()
                      .Add(fancyView1)
                      .Add(fancyView2);
fancyQueue.Show();
```

I am using a Xamarin.Android binding library of `FancyShowCaseView`, but you can review the Java-based examples are in the sample app in the repo, ie:[AnimatedActivity.java](https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/toptas/fancyshowcasesample/AnimatedActivity.java)

Also you can implement the `ME.Toptas.Fancyshowcase.IDismissListener` interface:

```
public void OnDismiss(string p0)
{
    // 
}

public void OnSkipped(string p0)
{
    //
}
```

And use that implementation on each of your FancyShowCaseViews:

```
var fancyView2 = new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(this)
                        .Title("StackOverflow 2")
                        .FocusOn(button2)
                        .DismissListener(this)
                        .Build();
```

Comment: hi there and thanks. unfortunately, FancyShowCaseQueue() doesnt exist in xamarin...

Comment: @innomotionmedia I'm not sure which version you are using but I am using a Xamarin.Android binding  library of `FancyShowCaseView-1.0.1.aar` That library was had FancyShowCaseQueue in it since its initial release:   https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/me/toptas/fancyshowcase/FancyShowCaseQueue.java

Comment: I know, I only have the Nuget package manager and this only include 1.0.0 :(

Comment: @innomotionmedia Which package are you using? And that class has be in there since the initial version `0.1.1` (16 releases ago)

Comment: sorry. what do you mean by which package? package of what? :)

Comment: @innomotionmedia Nuget package?

Comment: OH missunderstanding. The nuget package manager is an extension for visual studio to get support libaries and other components and install them into your project. from here i downloaded the fancyshowcaseview version 1.0.0. it does not have the 1.0.1 version :(

Comment: @innomotionmedia I know what the Nuget Package Manager is, I needed to know which package you are using (i.e. https://www.nuget.org/packages/FancyShowCaseView/) I just looked at that one and it is a C# "port" of the original Java-based and is not a complete port and thus is it missing *at least* a port of `FancyShowCaseQueue`, not sure if anything else is missing.... You can just create a Xamarin.Android binding library project and bind the original Java version (that is what I did) or of course you could port the rest of the Java code to C#...

Comment: okay great. unfortunately i have no idea of how to do either, if you could point me towardsa  tutorial i am going to do thatr! :)

Comment: @innomotionmedia https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/